# plot the data based the total count of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-analysis

I have a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a"," b", "c","d", "e"],
               'gender': ["m", "f", "f", "f", "m"],
              'year':[ 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2014],
              'count':[100, 30, 10, 90,34]})
```

I want to Plot the total number of males and females as a function of the year.
the output must look like this:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail? Also: What is name in your df? An irrelevant column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pivot table and plot directly. Below is an example with bar as result. Line is not good idea here as you have few years only:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.pivot_table(df, index='year', columns=['gender'], values='count', aggfunc='sum').plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]